Link Data to dropdown list
I have a sales tracking sheet. I have different employees on a dropdown list. I would like to create a summary sheet that will pull data in the row of the employee in the dropdown shift to one page that will keep a running total.
The reason I used dropdown is because the sales will be recorded in different orders and sometimes different categories.
Is there a way to link the data in the row to the right of the employee so that it is linked with the dropdown in order for me to create my running summary sheet?
I have considered that I could just create each employee on the same line. However this will not work as sometimes the employee will be categorized differently.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
